# POD::FETCH_CLASS causes infinite loop while PDO::FETCH_BOTH does not

Tags: php, pdo, infinite-loop

I've come across a difficult to track bug, but I'm not sure what is causing this bug. I have a class **Property** and I want to fetch one entry form the table **property** with a method named **loadProperty()**. This method is part from a singleton class (**Registry**).

```
public function loadProperty() {
    $this->load('model', 'property');
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM property WHERE subdomain = :subdomain LIMIT 1");
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'property');
    $data = array('subdomain' => $this->router->subdomain);

    try {
        $sth->execute($data);

        if ($sth->rowCount() == 1) {
            $this->property = $sth->fetch();
        } else {
            $this->property = null;
        }

    } catch (PDOException $exception) {
        // HANDLING EXCEPTION
    }
}
```

The first line of the method loads the model. It just looks for the class file and requires it with **require_once**.

All this works fine when I use PDO::FETCH_BOTH instead of PDO::FETCH_CLASS. My guess is that PDO is doing some things behind the scenes that I am not aware of, but that cause my loadProperty method to be called an infinite number of times.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: What does your `property` class look like?

Comment: Phil, even though you didn't give me the answer, your question was the right one at the right moment. In short, even though the Registry class is a singleton, I was calling its private constructor more than once. I wanted to do too much at once I guess. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @BartJacobs: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it ;) This will mark the question as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite loop turned out to be caused by an error of my own - who'd've thought. By setting PDO's fetch mode to **PDO::FETCH_CLASS**, **PDO** attempts to instantiate an instance of **Property**, which one might expect. However, the model creates a reference to the **Registry** class in its constructor method, causing the constructor of the **Registry** class to be invoked which includes the **loadProperty** method shown above. The result is an infinite loop.